# How to create and increment a number without the table length

Tags: javascript

I want to increment a number in the 1st column of each row of my table.
I want to make it without knowing the length of the data.

I tried this, and the number doesn't increment, but just display the variable value in each rows.

```js
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    if ($("#checker").val() == "ka") {
        var data = $("#report_all").serialize();

        $('#all_report thead').empty();
        $('#all_report tbody').empty();
        $.ajax({
            data: data,
            type: "Post",
            url: "../php/report/report_all_KA.php",
            success: function (data) {
                var list = JSON.parse(data);

                for (var x = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                    var n = 1;
                    n = list.length++;
                }
                var th = "";

                th += "<th>" + "<center>" + 'no' + "</center>" + "</th>";
                th += "<th>" + "<center>" + 'Tanggal' + "</center>" + "</th>";
                th += "<th>" + "<center>" + 'Type Kadar Air' + "</center>" + "</th>";
                th += "<th>" + "<center>" + 'Kode Material' + "</center>" + "</th>";
                th += "<th>" + "<center>" + 'Nama Material' + "</center>" + "</th>";
                th += "<th>" + "<center>" + 'Storage Location' + "</center>" + "</th>";
                th += "<th>" + "<center>" + 'Kadar Air' + "</center>" + "</th>";
                th += "<th>" + "<center>" + 'Nama PPIC' + "</center>" + "</th>";

                th += "</th>";
                $("#all_report thead").append(th);
                for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {

                    var tr = "<tr>";
                    tr += "<td>" + n + "</td>";
                    tr += "<td>" + list[i]['date'] + "</td>";
                    tr += "<td>" + list[i]['type'] + "</td>";
                    tr += "<td>" + list[i]['kode'] + "</td>";
                    tr += "<td>" + list[i]['nama'] + "</td>";
                    tr += "<td>" + list[i]['sloc'] + "</td>";
                    tr += "<td>" + list[i]['ka'] + "</td>";
                    tr += "<td>" + list[i]['ppic'] + "</td>";

                    tr += "</tr>";

                    $("#all_report tbody").append(tr);
                    $("#all_report").show();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    //[...]
```

The code that I made for the increment in the whole code above is like this.

```
for(var x = 0; i < list.length; i++){
  var n=1;
  n= list.length++;
}
```

Comment: Um, so use `i` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just looking for a column in your table that corresponds to the row numbers, you can replace `"<td>" +n+"</td>"` with `"<td>"+(i+1)+"</td>"`.

Then you won't even need that other loop!

Comment: just use the variable `i` for define the number?

Comment: Yep! `i` is a variable that's already being incremented by this `for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)` for loop

Comment: i have made the loop for it T_T

Answer (score 0):

```
var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0],
rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr'),
text = 'textContent' in document ? 'textContent' : 'innerText';
for (var i = 0, len = rows.length; i < len; i++) {
rows[i].children[0][text] = i + rows[i].children[0][text];
}
```

Hope it works! :)